# How to calculate the maximal error of a solution of a physical problem found numerically?

Tags: algorithms, estimation

Assume we throw a body from a height `h` with the velocity `v0` in some arbitrary direction. Beside the weight `W = mg`, another force `F(v)` is acting (suppose this can be any weird function). We want to solve this problem without integrals - numerically.

So we assume that in a very short time `dt` the force `F` is constant and calculate the motion of the body as if it consisted of a lot of phases lasting `dt`, with a constant force. We write a program for this.

How can we then estimate the accuracy of our results (the maximal error) if we calculate, for example, the time `T` after the body will fall to ground, the velocity or the coordinates at some arbitrary time `t_x`? Of course we know the step `dt`.